# breeze bug: setDeleted in forEach loop

Tags: breeze

I've encountered what I believe to be a bug in Breeze. To ensure the bug wasn't related to other code in my project, I have [***simulated the same issue in a plunker provided by Ward Bell***](http://plnkr.co/edit/hSTZt1XnU0riXVkqjMwV).

Code that I have added to Ward's original plunker is:

in main.html

```
<button ng-click="vm.deleteHero(vm.currentHeroVm.hero)">Delete hero</button>
```

and in main.js

```
vm.deleteHero = deleteHero;
    function deleteHero(hero) {
      console.log(hero.powerMaps.length);
      hero.powerMaps.forEach(function(powerMap) {
        console.log('Hero: ' + powerMap.heroId + ', Power: ' + powerMap.powerId);
        powerMap.entityAspect.setDeleted() // comment me out to see console.log work correctly
  });
}
```

to see the issue at hand, please note the `console.log` calls i'm making. The first displays the length of the `powerMaps` array for the selected hero. The second shows the hero and power ids for the powerMap inside the loop.

With a `hero` selected, open the console window and hit the `Delete` button.

If one comments out the line `powerMap.entityAspect.setDeleted()`, the application correctly loops through each `powerMap`.

However, as soon as `powerMap.entityAspect.setDeleted()` is added to the code, not every `powerMap` is reached.

The implication of this is that I currently cannot reliably loop through an array and delete entities. You'll note that if you continue to hit the delete button, the code does eventually get to all entities.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't delete entities that way. It's similar to looping through a list and deleting items from it as you go. It causes the list you're looping through to change as you progress and you'll end up skipping items.

Do this instead.

```
vm.deleteHero = deleteHero;

function deleteHero(hero) {
    console.log(hero.powerMaps.length);
    while (hero.powerMaps.length > 0) {
        var powerMap = hero.powerMaps[0];
        console.log('Hero: ' + powerMap.heroId + ', Power: ' + powerMap.powerId);
        powerMap.entityAspect.setDeleted() 
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks - This is a really valuable answer!

Comment: A question - is this as a result of the way the js forEach loops works inherently, or as a result of the way breeze's setDeleted responds to it?

Comment: setDeleted removes the item from the navigation property collection which is the thing you're currently looping through.

Comment: A good explanation to add to this might be the following - a foreach loop generally uses the index.  Imagine `delete(x) from n` where x is the index and n is the total count in the list.  foreach / `delete(0) from 3` then `delete(1) from 2` then `delete(2) from 1` **error there is no index position 2!**

Comment: @PWKad Just had an interesting situation where applying the while approach caused the browser to hang in a loop, but the foreach method worked. to a noob, it seems kinda inconsistent in its behaviour

Comment: @boomba that's JavaScript for you.

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy of `powerMaps` using `Array.slice()` and loop over it to delete your entities.

```
vm.deleteHero = deleteHero;
function deleteHero(hero) {
  hero.powerMaps.slice().forEach(function(powerMap) {
    powerMap.entityAspect.setDeleted()
  });
}
```

This is especially useful when you do not want to delete all relating entities and cannot use `while`.